# WebView load url in fragment from another class

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-jsinterface

I want to call method for loading URL in Fragment Class from other class , But I am getting null value for web view.                                               Below is my code.

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                              
     String url;
     Context context;
     public WebView webViewSite;

     public WebViewFragment()                                               
     {
     }
     public void init(String currentURL, Context context1) 
     {
         url = currentURL;
         context = context1;
     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup    container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_webview_site, container, false);
         webViewSite = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webViewSite);
         webViewSite.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webViewSite.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(context),"AndroidJSObject");
         webViewSite.setWebViewClient(new SwAWebClient());
         webViewSite.setWebChromeClient(new SwAWebChromeClient());
         loadURL(Configuration.MOBILE_SITE_URL);
         return view;
    }
    public  void loadURL(String url)
    {
        webViewSite.loadUrl(url, Configuration.appRequestHeaders);
    }

}
```

from below class i am calling loadURL method ,but for this i am getting null instance of webview.

```
      public class JsInterface                                                                                          
      {                                                                                                                         
           Handler myHandler;
           private Context mContext;  
           public JsInterface(Context c)
           {
               mContext = c;
               myHandler = new Handler();
           }
           @JavascriptInterface
           public void loadFromBaseUrl()
           {
              myHandler.post(new Runnable()
              {
                 @Override
                 public void run()
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(mContext,"Please Wait",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     new      WebViewFragment().loadURL(Configuration.MOBILE_SITE_URL);
                 }
             });
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`new WebViewFragment()` is making your webview null. Instead, you can make static method `loadURL` like:

```
 public static void loadURL(String url)
    {
        webViewSite.loadUrl(url, Configuration.appRequestHeaders);
    }
```

and call it like -

```
WebViewFragment.loadURL(Configuration.MOBILE_SITE_URL);
```